# How to create moving particles as mouse moves in html5, css3, or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this [404 page](http://www.webdesignshock.com/?p=8070), I can see the stars particle is moving as the mouse moving in different locations in the browser. I have no idea how to call this effect.

Can anyone provide a hint of the name of the effect and what is the right tool and how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Parallax, e.g. http://stephband.info/jparallax/ and many more when googling `jquery parallax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stars and every layer on that example are not particles. **They are fixed images using Parallax effect** as you can see on the elements that compose the page under the `div#container_layer`.

**This effect can be achieved from various ways.** The most common, responsive and best optimised solutions use JQuery, such as this one: http://wagerfield.github.io/parallax/

Basically the way this works is by using a number of layers and incrementing or decrementing their `absolute` or `relative` position based on the mouse's co-ordinates.

Comment: Pretty Cool example! I like it :)

Comment: @Chen You can find a lot of plugins that do the same thing, but this one is really one of the best optimised. As you see the difference between the performance on your example and on their sites example.

Comment: interesting, how could you see the performance difference? Do you mean CPU usage wise? Plz elaborate :D

Comment: Yes, not all browsers have the same GPU usage, so not all have the same site performance. When these animations start stuttering it is the first sign of low performance optimisation, you can notice this when comparing how fluid the animation rolls on your example and on this example: http://wagerfield.github.io/parallax/ Note that this is a very brief evaluation of the example in question.

Comment: I found this one.... is this how we do evaluation? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling?csw=1

Comment: To make a detailed evaluation on how Javascript is running you should have a pretty good understanding of the plugin's structure. But if you are looking for a nice performance optimised plugin, you should point out to the most fluid and most compatible plugin you can find. The example I gave you is pretty interesting and super flexible and has the capability of working with mobile devices' tilt gyroscope for these Parallax effects. By the way, you should read these plugins' documentation for a decent knowledge of their compatibility.

Comment: THanks! Great answers :) Appreciated